# Drag&Drop a row in the table using jQueryUI

Tags: jquery-ui-sortable, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm a newbie to Javascript, jQuery, all the client stuff.

I'm trying to drag and drop a " table row"  (each row has a label and 2 checkboxes) within the same table. I'm using jQueryUI's draggable and droppable. The problems I have are:

1. For eg. When I click/drag row 1, to row 3, then row 1 (all elements crunched in one `<td>`) gets set in the `<td>` of any given row that I'm dragging to.
2. The dragged row should be removed from the place it was dragged.

I have included the link [here](http://jsfiddle.net/tf49t/14/).

Answer (score 1):

A few things you'll want to do:

The draggable isn't needed (unless I misread what you're trying to do). All you need is to add a tbody tag around the tr's that you want to have sortable, like this:

```
<table width="350px" id="regFields">
    <thead>            
        <tr id="rowHeader">
            <th align="left" colspan="1">Field Name</th>
            <th align="center" colspan="1">Include</th>
            <th colspan="1"><ul>Required</ul></th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr class="row">
            <td align="left" colspan="1">First Name</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="firstNameInclude" name="firstNameInclude"></input></td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="firstNameRespReq" name="firstNameRespReq"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row">
            <td align="left" colspan="1">Last Name</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="lastNameInclude" name="lastNameInclude"></input></td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="lastNameRespReq" name="lastNameRespReq"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row">
            <td align="left" colspan="1">Company</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="companyInclude" name="companyInclude"></input></td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="companyRespReq" name="companyRespReq"></input></td>
        </tr>
        <tr id="row">
            <td align="left" colspan="1">Email</td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="emailInclude" name="emailInclude"></input></td>
            <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="emailRespReq" name="emailRespReq"></input></td>
         </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Also, note that you don't want to have multiple ids with the same name. Instead, you'll want classes. I didn't bother fixing that here but you'll want to do that.

The jQuery is actually pretty simple:

```
$('#regFields tbody').sortable({
    items: 'tr'
});
```

I'm selecting the table and the tbody element (so I don't get the header). Sortable automatically does the rest (probably don't even need the items option, but it doesn't hurt).

Hope this helps!

Jamon

Comment: Wow, awesome, that worked...Thank you so much Jamon!!!! Really appreciate it.. BTW, do you know any proper documentation for the JQuery and JQueryUI so newbies like me learn things the proper way not just learn randomly by trying different options found somewhere and get things working.....?

Comment: No problem. Do you mind marking my answer as the answer then? :)

As far as the proper documentation, start with the jQuery codex: http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page. jQuery UI also has demos and documentation here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/

Answer (score 0):

Try using sortable instead of draggable

```
<html>
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/jquery-ui-git.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="leftHalfContainer" style="display: block; float: left;">     
    <form name="setupRegForm" id="setupRegForm" method="post">                                            
    <table width="350px" id="regFields">
        <thead>            
            <tr id="rowHeader">
                <th align="left" colspan="1">Field Name</th>
                <th align="center" colspan="1">Include</th>
                <th colspan="1"><ul>Required</ul></th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
            <tr id="row">
                <td align="left" colspan="1">First Name</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="firstNameInclude" name="firstNameInclude"></input></td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="firstNameRespReq" name="firstNameRespReq"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row">
                <td align="left" colspan="1">Last Name</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="lastNameInclude" name="lastNameInclude"></input></td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="lastNameRespReq" name="lastNameRespReq"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row">
                <td align="left" colspan="1">Company</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="companyInclude" name="companyInclude"></input></td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="companyRespReq" name="companyRespReq"></input></td>
            </tr>
            <tr id="row">
                <td align="left" colspan="1">Email</td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="emailInclude" name="emailInclude"></input></td>
                <td align="center" colspan="1"><input type="checkbox" id="emailRespReq" name="emailRespReq"></input></td>
             </tr>
    </table>
    </form>                     
</div><script>
    $("table").sortable({
            items: 'tr'
    });   
</script>
</body>
</html>
```